# Wordpress - discord notification integration - hook issue

Tags: wordpress, discord

Any Idea why my hook is not triggering either sending notification to discord ?

```
<?php
    /*
    Plugin Name: Discord Registration Notification
    Description: Send notifications to Discord when a user registers.
    Version: 1.0
    */
    
    // Define the Discord bot endpoint where the notification should be sent
    $discord_bot_endpoint = 'https://discord.com/api/webhooks/1171354893924171787/5Exxxx_xxxF';
    
    // User registration event handling
    function on_user_register($user_id) {
        $user = get_userdata($user_id);
        $username = $user->user_login;
        $first_name = $user->first_name;
        $last_name = $user->last_name;
    
        $data = array(
            'username' => $username,
            'first_name' => $first_name,
            'last_name' => $last_name
        );
    
        $response = wp_safe_remote_post($discord_bot_endpoint, array(
            'body' => json_encode($data),
            'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'),
        ));
    
        if (is_wp_error($response)) {
            error_log('Failed to send data to Discord bot: ' . $response->get_error_message());
        }
    }
    
    add_action('user_register', 'on_user_register');
```

What I've done is I've added this code to my `tire/wp-content/plugins/Foxsoft/foxsoft.php`

Then I navigated to plugins and Activated this plugin.

Either I manually register on page or go through admin dashboard - > User - > Add new it simply doesn't "fire" .